# Polymer swipe-pages create by repeat

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

I try to use swipe-pages by template repeat.

```
   <swipe-pages>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{values}}">
          <swipe-page>
               <div>
                   Text to swipe
               </div>
          </swipe-page>
         </template>
   </swipe-pages>
```

In the polymer I wrote

```
created: function()  {
        console.log(this);
        this.values = [1,2,3];
       }
```

It give me the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'values' of undefined
  Polymer.created   
  Polymer.Base._addFeature._invokeBehavior  
  Polymer.Base._addFeature._doBehavior  
  Polymer.Base.createdCallback  
  window.Polymer    
  (anonymous function)  
  Polymer.DomApi.DomApi._addNode
```

I cant get it work.

Also use

```
ready:function(){this.values=[1,2,3];};
```

does not work. in this case it throws exception that their is 0 pages.

I think that the the swipe-pages does not receive the input after the template repeat run.

If I write it not by template it works ok..

update:

this is all the polymer-element.

```
<dom-module id="element-element">
          <template>
              <swipe-pages>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{values}}">
                   <swipe-page>
                     <div>
                        text
                     </div>
                   </swipe-page>
               </template>
              </swipe-pages>
           </template>
           <script>
               Polymer({
                    is:'element-element',
                    created: function()  {
                        this.values = [1,2,3];
                    },
                    ready: function(){
                        this.values=[1,2,3];
                    }
                });

            </script>
</dom-module>
```

If their is another swipe page element for polymer that can dynamically change I will be happy to know.

**If their is a hack solution (like load all  the element dynamically) it will be also ok**

Thanks.

Comment: Try use the `ready` callback instead (`ready: function() {}`)

Comment: I tried it.. then swipe-pages throws exception that it has 0 pages

Comment: In which element are you trying to set `this.values`? Can you share more code please?

Comment: @Ricky I updated the code. this is all the element.

Comment: @Ricky I will be happy to know if you know some polymer 1.0 element for swiping...that works with template repeat. this will help me. Thanks.

Comment: What `swipe-pages` are you using? Is it Polymer 1.0 compatible?

Comment: @JustinXL https://github.com/slogger/swipe-pages

Comment: This line in `swipe-pages` is blocking you - `<content id="pages" select="swipe-page"></content>`...It can't select `swipe-page` because when it tries to `getDistributedNodes()` it returns an empty array, that is, zero pages. So the fix will require either a pull request to `swipe-pages` or use an alternative.

Comment: Their is an alternative (I searched and didnt find)? that works with repeat?
It is possible to bind the content? so it will render only after the template loop finish ?

Comment: I think about ugly solution.. creating 20 pages and then change them..
Then I dont have to use the repeat. But this is very ugly.. Or somehow in get into the shadow dom and dont use getDistributedNodes() but another function..

Comment: Have you considered `neon-animated-pages` as an alternative solution?

Comment: I saw this but it does not support swipe. (or I mistake)

Comment: check this: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/iron-swipeable-pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix is to modify `swipe-pages`'s source code.

First, go find the `selectedChanged` function and add this check at the very top -

```
selectedChanged: function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (oldValue === undefined) {
        return;
    }

    if (newValue >= this.pageCount || newValue < 0) {
        ....
```

Then, because `resetPositions` and `resetWidths` are called too early, you want to replace the following

```
ready: function () {
    this.resetPositions();
    this.resetWidths();
}
```

with

```
attached: function () {
    this.async(function () {
        this.resetPositions();
        this.resetWidths();
    }, 5);
```

to make sure the pages are already rendered via `dom-repeat`.

Lastly, make sure you initialize the array inside either `ready` or `attached`.

```
ready: function()  {
    console.log(this);
    this.values = [1,2,3];
}
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this: [argon-swipeable-pages](https://customelements.io/krocon/argon-swipeable-pages/)!

```
<argon-swipeable-pages items="[[ data ]]" as="person" index-as="pix">
    <template>
        <p>Name: [[ person.name ]]</p>
        <p>Age: [[ person.age ]]</p>
        <p>Index: [[ pix ]]</p>
    </template>
</argon-swipeable-pages>
```